# iconv-lite package undefined problem when written by typescript

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I installed the "iconv-lite" package, imported the module, and called the decode method, but the following error occurs.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decode')

But the strange thing is that when it is executed by JavaScript language, it works without any problem.

below is the code I wrote.

```
import iconv from "iconv-lite" 

import cheerio from "cheerio"  
import axios from "axios"


async function getHtml() {
    try{
        const htmlData = await axios.get("https://news.naver.com/main/main.naver?mode=LSD&mid=shm&sid1=101", {
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
    })
        return htmlData
    }catch(e){
        console.log("ERROR IS: "+e)
    } }

export async function getNews() : Promise<object> {
    let newsBox = []
    const res = await getHtml()
    const content = iconv.decode(res.data, "EUC-KR").toString()
    const $ = cheerio.load(content)
    const list = $("ul li")
    list.each((index, elem) => {
        let newsObj :{headLine:string, content:string, img:string} = {
            headLine: $(elem).find("div.cluster_text a.cluster_text_headline").text(),
            content : $(elem).find("div.cluster_text div.cluster_text_lede").text(),
            img : $(elem).find("div.cluster_thumb img").attr("src")
        }
        if (newsObj.headLine != '' && newsObj.img != undefined && newsObj.content != '') newsBox.push(newsObj)
    })
    console.log(newsBox)
    return newsBox }
```

below is the error-message corresponded with above code.

> C:\react_practice\news_recommendation_project\news_board_back\src\article>ts-node
> getArticle.ts
> C:\react_practice\news_recommendation_project\news_board_back\src\article\getArticle.ts:19
> const content = iconv.decode(res.data, "EUC-KR").toString()
> ^ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decode')
> at getNews (C:\react_practice\news_recommendation_project\news_board_back\src\article\getArticle.ts:19:27)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I wonder why this error occurs.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be related to the Nest.js framework. It's not about a typescript problem. Because if I run it outside the Nest.js project directory, there are no errors and it works. So did I solve this problem? yes I did. I modified the import statement as follows,

before -> import iconv from "iconv-lite"
after -> import * as iconv from "iconv-lite"

and it was also executed in the Nestjs project directory. Hope this helps if anyone has this kind of problem.